# Why do my svg nodes leak memory in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, svg, d3.js

*Background: Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364956/are-event-listeners-for-removed-automatically-when-using-remove-in-d3-js) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382286/d3-js-should-i-detach-event-listener-on-exit-remove) about D3 memory usage I decided to dig into how it really works, and soon came upon [cautions about repeated add/remove of DOM nodes in IE](http://com.hemiola.com/2009/11/23/memory-leaks-in-ie8/).*

To isolate from whatever else D3 was doing, I first tried the basic SVG case of adding/removing 1000 circles every second:

```js
var count = 1000;
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute('width', '800');
svg.setAttribute('height', '800');
document.body.appendChild(svg);

function update() {
  // remove existing circles
  var circles = svg.querySelectorAll("circle")
  for (var i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var parent = circles[i].parentNode;
    if (parent) parent.removeChild(circles[i]);
  };

  // add new ones. Yes, would make more sense to update the x,y on the existing
  // circles but this is to show what happens in IE with lots of nodes being added/removed
  for (var j = count - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
    node.id = 'id' + Math.random();
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", Math.random()*800);
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "cy", Math.random()*800);
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "r",  5);
    node.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "blue");
    svg.appendChild(node);
  };
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
```

I found that this slowly leaks memory in both IE9 and IE10. See here for live version: http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6413259

**What (if anything) can I do to prevent the leak, and what implications does this have for how D3 code targeting IE should be written that adds/removes a lot of nodes?**

Other notes:

Inspired by [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/static-mem-pools/), I tried a simple node pool approach by pushing the removed nodes on to a stack:

```
if (parent) circlePool.push( parent.removeChild(circles[i]) );
```

And reusing them later:

```
var node;
if (circlePool.length == 0) {
  node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'circle');
} else {
  node = circlePool.pop();
  //TODO: clear out attributes of the node
}
```

But this did not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've found so far that helps with IE memory usage is to **not** assign IDs to the nodes, or to assign them IDs that repeat across iterations of the animation:

```
node.id = 'id' + j;
```

See the live version here: http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/6413371

I thought that nulling the ID prior to removing the DOM node would do the same thing, but this had no effect.

I don't really like this answer so I'm hoping that someone else comes along with a better explanation of why the node pool approach didn't work.

But for now, the moral of the story for developers using D3: if you're repeatedly adding and then removing lots of nodes with unique IDs (e.g. from .ajax calls which get records out of db), you might be in danger of a memory leak.